# External Hard Disk is not empty but files are not being displayed

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, filesystem-corruption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [External Hard Disk is not empty but files are not being displayed](https://superuser.com/questions/356279/external-hard-disk-is-not-empty-but-files-are-not-being-displayed)

My external hard disk has data on it. When I right click and see properties it says has 189GB occupied, but I am unable to see any files in it. It is of NTFS format. The files are not hidden, it seems to be corrupted in some way.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: I want to add that I had this problem with an SSD I removed while the computer was on. I was stuck for days, then I went to the Drive > Properties > Tools > Optimize and ran it. Then the files showed up. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using the drive on another computer, you may not have permission to access the files on the drive on your current computer. You will need to take ownership of the whole drive to access the files. If you want to use the drive on multiple computers, you should share the drive with "Everyone", this will allow you to access the drive on any computer.

Comment: I have been using the hard drive previously on other computers, then what happened to it all of a sudden? How should I take the ownership of the hard disk.