# External Hard Disk is not empty but files are not being displayed

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs

My external hard disk has data on it. When I right click and see properties it says has 189GB occupied, but I am unable to see any files in it. It is of NTFS format. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with it

Comment: Likely the files are hidden. In the folder press alt, go to tools-> folder options -> view -> show hidden files and folders

Comment: No they are not hidden, the disk is corrupted in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mounting the drive with a linux livecd with NTFS 3G and see if the files are visible. If so, copy out the data, then reformat - in my experience, its worked both times i have encountered this situation

If that fails, try [testdisc](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) to see if you can recover the drive.